# Can't use Jupyter Notebook: jsonschema apparently missing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, package, jupyter

When using an Anaconda environment, I can't start Jupyter to work in a notebook.  I can do so without the environment, but I need to be able to use the environment.  Here's what I do and the errors I get:

```
ben@ben-K60IJ:~/surveillance_sound_classifier/surveillance_sound_classifier$ source activate EECS352
discarding /home/ben/anaconda/bin from PATH
prepending /home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/bin to PATH
(EECS352)ben@ben-K60IJ:~/surveillance_sound_classifier/surveillance_sound_classifier$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 61, in <module>
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 16, in <module>
from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
  File "/home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "/home/ben/anaconda/envs/EECS352/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 21, in <module>
raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: No module named functools32

Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

Please install it first.
```

Yes, I've done `pip install jsonschema` and `conda install jsonschema` AND `pip install functools32` and `conda install functools32` from **within** the EECS352 environment to no avail; I arrive at an almost identical error, except this time, `functools32` is replaced with `_version`.

I've reinstalled Anaconda, updated all its packages, created a new environment in the same way I created this one, and still I get this error. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit.  I used to be able to use this environment with no problems until roughly a week ago.

If this is a duplicate, please point me to the original; however, I haven't yet found anything that seems really relevant.  The only thing that might be relevant is that this error did pop up after I modified some `.conf` file because I was having issues updating my computer's software using `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  I don't recall what I had done and to which file, but if it's likely the source of this issue, I can spend some time trying to track it down.  Please let me know if I should spend my time to do this, and I will.

Comment: Did you install the requirements within your virtualenv of EECS352?

Comment: What do you mean by "requirements"?  I'm using the exact same environment that was working roughly a week ago.  Nothing in the environment has changed.

Comment: requirements in this sense meaning the `jsonschema` package and `functools32`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't specify that I did both the `pip` and `conda` `install` of `jsonschema` and `functools32` from __within__ the EECS352 environment.  I'll update my question, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I have the same problem. I installed jupyter some weeks ago. But today, using anaconda, it fails to launch for the same jsonschema library.

Comment: @BenSandeen did you solve the problem? I think is something wrong with the anaconda distribution. I installed anaconda on a fresh system and I hit in the same problem. But ```pip install --upgrade jsonschema``` (as described below) solved it.

Comment: Nope, I haven't solved it, I just worked around it since it was finals week and since then, I haven't really need it anymore, so I haven't bothered too much with it

Comment: I tried all of the posted solutions but unfortunately none of them worked for me. In the end, I solved it by creating a new conda environment. This may not be a solution but might be good to know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I have a solution.

I did may things, regenerated my env (anaconda env) from another computer where it worked, but no success.

What I think that nailed it is upgrading jsonschema to 2.5.1

Here are my steps from "bad" jupyter env to working jupyter env.

Good luck and come back if it doesn't work, I will post the notebook* relevant versions.

```
>conda upgrade pip
pip:        8.1.0-py27_0  --> 8.1.1-py27_0
setuptools: 20.2.2-py27_0 --> 20.3-py27_0 

>pip install functools32
Downloading functools32-3.2.3-2.tar.gz    
Successfully installed functools32-3.2.3.post2

>jupyter notebook
ImportError: No module named _version
Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema
Please install it first.

>pip install jsonschema
Requirement already satisfied

>pip install --upgrade jsonschema
Collecting jsonschema
Downloading jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Successfully uninstalled jsonschema-2.4.0
Successfully installed jsonschema-2.5.1

>jupyter notebook
[I 16:45:41.708 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to 
[I 16:45:42.134 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: 
[I 16:45:42.134 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:45:42.134 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
```

Comment: What is weird is that I cloned a working env using `conda list -e` command. There I have the old jsonschema (2.4.0). Beats me where is the conflict or what other dependencies are not listed by anaconda. On working env I installed stuff directly from github with `python setup.py`. I don't know how conda/pip monitor/knows what is installed or not and at this point I am too afraid to ask :)

Answer (score 5):

i also got the same error and none of the above mentioned procedures worked for me so i've checked the documentation of anaconda and found something useful

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 jsonschema`

`conda install jupyter`

`jupyter notebook`

this worked for me,thanks to anaconda documentation

Answer (score 4):

Re-install `jsonschema` solve the problem in my case:

```sh
$ pip uninstall jsonschema
...

$ pip install jsonschema
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above mentioned solution didn't work then try this in your anaconda prompt: First run `conda update -n root conda` so you have the latest conda version installed. Then run `conda update --all` This will update all packages in the current environment to the latest version.
Even after installing jsonschema, your Jupyter Notebook might not run and give you the error:

> Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:
> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema
> Please install it first

Then I suggest you to run the given two commands. It will solve your issue as it solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the terminal:

```
pip install ipython[notebook]
```

It worked for me, let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Ipython is deprecate3d and called jupyter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by running this command

```
conda install -c anaconda jsonschema
```

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jsonschema

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

upgrade it using

```
conda install -c conda-forge jsonschema
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have the notebook package installed in both the global python and the python environment you're working in. In my case I did, so I ran `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` in both my global python and inside the python environment. This deletes any packages that were installed using pip so you would need to reinstall the packages you already had. Then I ran `pip3 install notebook` inside my environment. Then running `jupyter notebook` worked without any errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try this from terminal, it worked to me:

```
pip install --upgrade pyrsistent
```