# Unable to get to Jupiter Notebook and Jsonschema Missing

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.6, jupyter

I have been solving issues with my MacBook Air for the past day and I have unfortunately again bumped into some more issues. You might have seen this question before, but I couldn't solve this issue after trying all answers from

[Can't use Jupyter Notebook: jsonschema apparently missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903535/cant-use-jupyter-notebook-jsonschema-apparently-missing)

Basically, I am now trying to enter Jupyter Notebook. I (think I) have two of them, one Jupyter Notebook installed using pip3 (Python 3.6.0), and one from Anaconda, which I uninstalled. For Anaconda, although I used anaconda clean and the rm function according to their official website and several other Stack Overflow forums, I could not uninstall the BASH and so I just left it there and installed Jupyter Notebook using pip3. But when I type Jupyter Notebook in Terminal, there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_distribution'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_distribution'

    Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

    Please install it first.
```

What I am using:
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Macbook Air 2011 i7 4gb ram 
Python 3.6.0 (pip3 to install Jupyter)
What I have installed in Python: Numpy, Pandas, Tensorflow, Keras

Thank you for helping! Please point out any errors or ways I can improve this question if possible. Also, try to answer solutions differently from [Can't use Jupyter Notebook: jsonschema apparently missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903535/cant-use-jupyter-notebook-jsonschema-apparently-missing) .