# Unable to launch jupyter notebook supposedly due to jsonschema

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I started facing this error after installing `keras via - conda install -c conda-forge keras`.

Now when I try to launch Jupiter notebook I am prompted with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata
ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib' (C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata as metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\srish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'

    Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

    Please install it first.
```

The solution of the following link seems to be outdated, and is for python 2.7 only: [Can't use Jupyter Notebook: jsonschema apparently missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903535/cant-use-jupyter-notebook-jsonschema-apparently-missing).

Answer (score 3):

Your Solution Worked for me. I had originally upgraded to jsonschema 3.20. I then downgraded to version jsonschema 3.02 and now my Jupyter notebook opens. Don't know why the higher version 3.20  creates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well I also felt the same problem and my notebook or lab was also not opening. I found an answer in an website. I used the command **`conda install jsonschema==3.0.2`** in the Anaconda Prompt and after installing my notebook and lab works fine again.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind what version of anaconda you're using, downgrading anaconda to the 2020.02 version solved it for me (using `conda install anaconda=2020.02`).

This happend to me when I updated anaconda to the 2020.07 version using `conda install anaconda=2020.07`. I tried `conda install jsonschema==3.0.2` as @user14080268 mentioned, but this caused the solving environment to fail and it went to look for incompatible packages, which then took for ever. Downgrading anaconda back to the version I initially had fixed the issue for me!

(of course, if you had a specific reason to update anaconda this might not be the best solution for you)