# Can't open jupyter notebook due to jsonschema [already tried other solutions on stackoverflow]

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jsonschema

I am using python 3.8 on Windows 10 machine.
I normally use VS Code and ipynb (without anaconda) inside it and everything was running smoothly
A couple days ago, I started to het the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    __version__ = metadata.version("jsonschema")
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 531, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 504, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 177, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: jsonschema

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kshit\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Programming\Python\Installation\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "c:\users\kshit\onedrive - university of waterloo\programming\python\installation\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: jsonschema

    Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

    Please install it first.
```

I tried to search for solutions on stackoverflow: 
[Can't use Jupyter Notebook: jsonschema apparently missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903535/cant-use-jupyter-notebook-jsonschema-apparently-missing)

But none of the answers there worked for me.

I tried upgrading jsonschema, jupyter and pip itself several times but to no avail.
Tried running it in Pycharm too, 
And I believe I have not changed anything in my python environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kshitij.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip - it will throw some errors. You should do so from the website. A temporary solution to jupyter notebook is Google Colab - colab.research.withgoogle.com. It also uses .ipynb. Hope this helps!

Comment: um why shouldn't you use `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Sometimes it throws an error, the pip code throws an error sometimes. You might want to download the new version from the website.